Writing helper type to remove defaults from a type
Let's say we have this type:
type T<A = object, B = number> = {
  a: A,
  b: B,
}

What I want is to remove a default type from template parameters, for example:
type TNoDefault = RemoveDefaults<T>; 

Generated TNoDefault will have no default arguments to A and B, so we must provide them when using type, like this TNoDefault<number, number>.
How the RemoveDefaults type can be implemented, or is it even possible?

Impossible. TS lacks higher kinded types (so you cannot pass around generic type names this way) See microsoft/TypeScript#1213. Does that fully address the question? If so I’ll write an answer explaining or find a duplicate. If not, what’s missing?

@jcalz Yeah, that's pretty much what I wanted, I didn't know how to google it because I tend to call it templated template and all this stuff, Thank you the github issue you provided is what I was looking for, hope TS team will ever find time to implement it)
